# Plugin to Interact Nativescript with native Mapbox SDK

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want turn by turn navigation (like a GPS system) from point A to point B. In order to achieve this, I need to create a “plugin” to allow NativeScript to interact with the native Mapbox SDK.
I wanted some information on how to create plugins in Nativescript. Since I am very new to the technology , I wanted to know how much time estimate it will taek to achieve this for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with handing navigation over to the native Maps app then you can have the user select a destination (and possibly departure and waypoints) and use the nativescript-directions plugin to launch the Apple/Google Maps app.

Here's an example of how that could work: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-pluginshowcase/blob/6551bf101641afa685093b22275e92d730ebe107/app/mapping/mapping.component.ts#L109-L112 (sorry, I'm not gonna copy-paste all that code here).